# Do I need foci to calculate an ellipse?

Tags: geometry

I have been trying to find an answer, but where I look does not tell me why I need foci if I have all $4$ vertices and the center. If I am just trying to create an ellipse with the $4$ vertices and center, can I just plug the numbers into the equation of an ellipse without worrying about the foci? I am trying to understand how the foci come into play, as they don't appear in the actual equation of an ellipse. However, I want my ellipse to be correct. I am trying to take a circle, and scale the y axis only, elongating the circle to create the ellipse that still passes through the $4$ points, $2$ now scaled. It is a vertical ellipse. Tia!

Comment: If you have vertices , then you know foci( indirectly )..

Comment: Well, locating the foci is important. This will be used to find the length of latus rectum

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan: your comment is misleading. For this question, working with the foci would be counterproductive.

Comment: I think Gen san's comment is correct and on the point, as the OP is asking very centered about foci and how to construct an ellipse. The very geometric definition of an ellipse as the locus of all points the sum of whose distance to two fixed points (the foci!) is constant, can make this a rather simple work. Take a peek at this nice video> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Et3OdzEGX_w

Comment: What does it mean to *calculate an ellipse*? If you have the vertices you also have the foci, due to the relation $a^2-b^2=c^2$, where $2a$ is the length of the major axis, $2b$ is the length of the minor axis and $2c$ is the distance between the foci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $2a,2b$ from the given points. If you want to calculate an ellipse from relation

$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 $$

which has axes parallel to coordinate axes that is taken implied for your exercise, you can use

$$ y= b \sqrt{1-x^2/a^2} $$

to find $y$ for each $x.$

(Foci location, latus rectum, eccentricity) are related parameters that is not required for above calculation).

Answer (score 0):

If you know your the vertices, you know the principal axes, and the equation of the ellipse in a orthogonal system of coordinates adapted to the axes. Hence the equation of the ellipse in the original system (O,i,j)
can be obtained by a linear change of coordinate.

So the answer to your question is : no, you don't need the foci to calculate the ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

Foci of an ellipse are used to find the eccentricity. The very definition of ellipse is also based on the sum of distances from the points on the ellipse to foci.

Answer (score 0):

The general equation of an ellipse is a quadratic expression

$$ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$

where the foci do not appear explicitly.

In the case of an axis-parallel ellipse, the cross term $xy$ does not exist, and you can use the simplified form

$$\frac{(x-x_c)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-y_c)^2}{b^2}=1$$ where the center and axis lengths are explicit.